# While loop to determine if entered value is a double

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, double

I'm working on a rather larger project and this is just included in it. Basically I created a class that takes an employee's info, we need to have it so the user must enter in a double for their pay rate. Say 8.00. Note the user CANNOT add in a dollar sign such as $8.00, else it will prompt the user an error has occured. Yet when I test run the code, instead of using the error prompt, the code simply crashes.

```
public static double getPayRate()
 {
    double payRate;
    System.out.println("Please enter the employee's pay rate (a numeric value): ");
    payRate = console.nextDouble();
    while(console.hasNextDouble())
    {
        System.out.println("An error occured with your input...");
        System.out.println("Please enter the employee's pay rate (a numeric value): ");
        payRate = console.nextDouble();
    }
    return payRate;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can we get a stacktrace? At first glance, console could be undefined (which would throw a NPE).

Comment: Do I need to sound the usual warning about using floating-point types to store an amount of money?

Comment: From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) _This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value_. You need to catch the exception. Or better yet read the value as a `String` then parse it using `Double.parseDouble` after checking.

Comment: Well the employee name, pay rate hours and his employee number must be validated. So I don't think I can parse it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error handling reading ints from Scanner in while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393156/error-handling-reading-ints-from-scanner-in-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so using the code you have, a way to go about this is like so..
While this code works to retrieve a double value, it is not recommended to use double when dealing with money, refer to this post for more information.
[Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SOTest {

    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static double getPayRate()
     {
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the employee's pay rate (a numeric value):");
            try {
                return Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("An error occured with your input...");
            }
        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getPayRate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote removed as the code is no longer brazenly wrong. It's still horribly messy and I would not recommend that anyone actually use it however. You could just `while(true)` and return the result of the parse directly.

Comment: I never said I recommended it. I showed him how to do code that would work for what he is trying to do.

Comment: By answering you _have_ recommended it.

Comment: Posting an answer containing code constitutes recommending that code.  If you don't recommend it, don't post it.

Comment: I recommend it as a fix for his current code. It works as intended. You are just picking a fight for no reason. Like I said, go answer the question yourself then.

Comment: No need to argue you two. Thank you Tristan for the help. It is much appreciated.