# Error handling reading ints from Scanner in while loop

Tags: java

I am try to catch an exception and get it to repeat, but it just creates an endless loop and then crashes the program... why is it doing this? Is it something wrong with my catch?

I have looked around the web and stackoverflow and can only find answers that don't related to what I am trying to achieve.

```
        boolean bError = true;
        System.out.println("How many players");
        do
        {
            try
            {
                PLAYERS = input.nextInt();

                if(PLAYERS > 5)
                {
                    System.out.println("maximum of 5");
                }//if
                else
                {
                    bError = false;
                }

            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                bError = true;
            }

        }while(bError && PLAYERS > 5);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input that produces the problem you describe?

Comment: Hi Jason, for example "a" instead of an integer

Comment: Shouldn't the stop condition by using or instead of and?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes into an endless loop if you enter an invalid number because the invalid token is still left on the stream, and `nextInt()` keeps trying over and over again to grab it.

You will have to get the data off the stream.

One thing you could do is use `nextLine()` instead, then explicitly try and parse the returned `String` into an integer (e.g. with `Integer.parseInt()`).

Another thing you could do is call `input.next()` (or `input.nextLine()`) in the exception handler, to read (and discard) the garbage input. You may have to tweak the `Scanner` delimiters to get `next()` to work for you if it's not meeting your requirements with default settings.