# How do I make sure that a string value is not passed into an int variable?

Tags: java, validation, exception, inputmismatchexception

I am still very new to programming.  I've only taken three programming classes, one in C++ and two in Java.

I decided I wanted to build my own version of Battleship.  I've more or less got the entire project finished.  My issue has been providing means of user validation to make sure that the user is actually inputting valid information.

I have a huge chunk of code inside of nested do-while loops, each one repeating if a specific condition returns false.

I've created a Board class that represents the game boards.  This is the code minus the methods.

```
public class Board
{

// Create class-wide arrays to represent each board
private static int p1[][] = new int[10][10];
private static int p2[][] = new int[10][10];

// Create other class-wide variables
private static int p1Targets[][] = new int[10][10];
private static int p2Targets[][] = new int[10][10];
private static int boatOneLocationP1[][] = new int[2][2];
private static boolean boatOneP1Sunk = false;
private static int boatTwoLocationP1[][] = new int[3][2];
private static boolean boatTwoP1Sunk = false;
private static int boatThreeLocationP1[][] = new int[3][2];
private static boolean boatThreeP1Sunk = false;
private static int boatFourLocationP1[][] = new int[4][2];
private static boolean boatFourP1Sunk = false;
private static int boatFiveLocationP1[][] = new int[5][2];
private static boolean boatFiveP1Sunk = false;
private static int boatOneLocationP2[][] = new int[2][2];
private static boolean boatOneP2Sunk = false;
private static int boatTwoLocationP2[][] = new int[3][2];
private static boolean boatTwoP2Sunk = false;
private static int boatThreeLocationP2[][] = new int[3][2];
private static boolean boatThreeP2Sunk = false;
private static int boatFourLocationP2[][] = new int[4][2];
private static boolean boatFourP2Sunk = false;
private static int boatFiveLocationP2[][] = new int[5][2];
private static boolean boatFiveP2Sunk = false;

}
```

This is the entire placeBoats() method
This is my placeBoats() method.  The Player class has a static variable for the total number of Player objects created and each object has its own unique player number.

```
void placeBoats(Player p, Scanner kb)
{
    // Player is shown a menu, he must select all 5 options to place his
    // boats.
    // Once user has selected which boat he is placing, display the ocean
    // and ask the user for start and end coordinates

    // Use arrays for Menu Choices and for User Choices
    int[] menuChoices = new int[5];
    int[] userChoices = new int[5];

    // Initialize arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < userChoices.length; i++)
    {
        userChoices[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < menuChoices.length; i++)
    {
        /*
         * 1. Two-Length Ship 2. Three-Length Ship 1 3. Three-Length Ship 2
         * 4. Four-Length Ship 5. Five-Length Ship
         * 
         * Repeat the do-while loop until userChoices[] == 1.
         */
        menuChoices[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // Begin do-while loop
    int num = 0;
    int boatLength = 0;
    int row1 = 0, col1 = 0, row2 = 0, col2 = 0;
    boolean notReady = true;
    boolean boatPresent = false;
    boolean validCoords = false;
    String starting, ending;

    do
    { // Jump to end
        do
        { // Jump to Place Boats
            boatPresent = false;

            do
            { // Jump to boat validation (making sure no boats already exist
                // in area)
                validCoords = false;
                // Display Menu
                System.out.println("Menu");
                if (menuChoices[0] == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("1. Two-Length Ship");
                }

                if (menuChoices[1] == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("2. Three-Length Ship 1");
                }

                if (menuChoices[2] == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("3. Three-Length Ship 2");
                }

                if (menuChoices[3] == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("4. Four-Length Ship");
                }

                if (menuChoices[4] == 5)
                {
                    System.out.println("5. Five-Length Ship");
                }

                // Get user input
                System.out.print("\nEnter your menu choice:  ");
                num = kb.nextInt();
                kb.nextLine();
                // Input Validation- input must be a valid menu choice
                while ((num != 1 && num != 2 && num != 3 && num != 4 && num != 5))
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter your menu choice:  ");
                    num = kb.nextInt();
                    kb.nextLine();
                }
                // Further Validation- Make sure number has not been picked
                // before yet
                while (userChoices[num - 1] == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter your menu choice:  ");
                    num = kb.nextInt();
                    kb.nextLine();
                }

                // Set boat length
                if (num == 1)
                    boatLength = 2;
                if (num == 2)
                    boatLength = 3;
                if (num == 3)
                    boatLength = 3;
                if (num == 4)
                    boatLength = 4;
                if (num == 5)
                    boatLength = 5;

                // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Display ocean
                if (p.getPlayerNumber() == 1)
                {
                    showP1Board();
                    System.out.println();
                }

                if (p.getPlayerNumber() == 2)
                {
                    showP2Board();
                    System.out.println();
                }

                // Ask the user for the start and end coordinates (as a
                // String)
                System.out.print("Enter the starting coordinate for a "
                        + boatLength + "-length ship:  \n");
                starting = kb.nextLine();
                // Validate - Make sure the given values are valid
                while (starting.charAt(0) != 'A'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'B'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'C'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'D'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'E'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'F'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'G'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'H'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'I'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'J'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'a'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'b'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'c'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'd'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'e'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'f'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'g'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'h'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'i'
                        && starting.charAt(0) != 'j')
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter the starting coordinate for a "
                            + boatLength + "-length ship:  ");
                    starting = kb.nextLine();
                }
                while (starting.charAt(1) != '1'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '2'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '3'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '4'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '5'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '6'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '7'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '8'
                        && starting.charAt(1) != '9')
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter the starting coordinate for a "
                            + boatLength + "-length ship:  ");
                    starting = kb.nextLine();
                }

                System.out.println("[" + starting.charAt(0) + "]["
                        + starting.charAt(1) + "]");

                System.out.println();
                // Set Row and Column 1
                switch (starting.charAt(0))
                {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'A':
                        row1 = 0;
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                    case 'B':
                        row1 = 1;
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                    case 'C':
                        row1 = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                    case 'D':
                        row1 = 3;
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                    case 'E':
                        row1 = 4;
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                    case 'F':
                        row1 = 5;
                        break;
                    case 'g':
                    case 'G':
                        row1 = 6;
                        break;
                    case 'h':
                    case 'H':
                        row1 = 7;
                        break;
                    case 'i':
                    case 'I':
                        row1 = 8;
                        break;
                    case 'j':
                    case 'J':
                        row1 = 9;
                        break;
                } // end switch statement

                switch (starting.charAt(1))
                {
                    case 49:
                    case 1:
                        col1 = 0;
                        break;
                    case 50:
                    case 2:
                        col1 = 1;
                        break;
                    case 51:
                    case 3:
                        col1 = 2;
                        break;
                    case 52:
                    case 4:
                        col1 = 3;
                        break;
                    case 53:
                    case 5:
                        col1 = 4;
                        break;
                    case 54:
                    case 6:
                        col1 = 5;
                        break;
                    case 55:
                    case 7:
                        col1 = 6;
                        break;
                    case 56:
                    case 8:
                        col1 = 7;
                        break;
                    case 57:
                    case 9:
                        col1 = 8;
                        break;
                }

                System.out.println(starting.length());

                if (starting.length() >= 3)
                {
                    if ((starting.charAt(1) == 1 || starting.charAt(1) == 49)
                            && (starting.charAt(2) == 0 || starting
                                    .charAt(2) == 48))
                    {
                        col1 = 9;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Row1 = " + row1 + "\tCol1 = " + col1);

                // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                System.out.print("Enter the ending coordinate for a "
                        + boatLength + "-length ship:  \n");
                ending = kb.nextLine();
                // Validate - Make sure the given values are valid
                while (ending.charAt(0) != 'A' && ending.charAt(0) != 'B'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'C'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'D'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'E'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'F'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'G'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'H'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'I'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'J'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'a'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'b'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'c'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'd'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'e'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'f'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'g'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'h'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'i'
                        && ending.charAt(0) != 'j')
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter the ending coordinate for a "
                            + boatLength + "-length ship:  ");
                    ending = kb.nextLine();
                }
                while (ending.charAt(1) != '1' && ending.charAt(1) != '2'
                        && ending.charAt(1) != '3'
                        && ending.charAt(1) != '4'
                        && ending.charAt(1) != '5'
                        && ending.charAt(1) != '6'
                        && ending.charAt(1) != '7'
                        && ending.charAt(1) != '8'
                        && ending.charAt(1) != '9')
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter the ending coordinate for a "
                            + boatLength + "-length ship:  ");
                    ending = kb.nextLine();
                }

                System.out.println("[" + ending.charAt(0) + "]["
                        + ending.charAt(1) + "]");

                System.out.println();

                // Set Row and Column 2
                switch (ending.charAt(0))
                {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'A':
                        row2 = 0;
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                    case 'B':
                        row2 = 1;
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                    case 'C':
                        row2 = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                    case 'D':
                        row2 = 3;
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                    case 'E':
                        row2 = 4;
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                    case 'F':
                        row2 = 5;
                        break;
                    case 'g':
                    case 'G':
                        row2 = 6;
                        break;
                    case 'h':
                    case 'H':
                        row2 = 7;
                        break;
                    case 'i':
                    case 'I':
                        row2 = 8;
                        break;
                    case 'j':
                    case 'J':
                        row2 = 9;
                        break;
                } // end switch statement

                switch (ending.charAt(1))
                {
                    case 49:
                    case 1:
                        col2 = 0;
                        break;
                    case 50:
                    case 2:
                        col2 = 1;
                        break;
                    case 51:
                    case 3:
                        col2 = 2;
                        break;
                    case 52:
                    case 4:
                        col2 = 3;
                        break;
                    case 53:
                    case 5:
                        col2 = 4;
                        break;
                    case 54:
                    case 6:
                        col2 = 5;
                        break;
                    case 55:
                    case 7:
                        col2 = 6;
                        break;
                    case 56:
                    case 8:
                        col2 = 7;
                        break;
                    case 57:
                    case 9:
                        col2 = 8;
                        break;
                }

                if (ending.length() >= 3)
                {
                    if ((ending.charAt(1) == 1 || ending.charAt(1) == 49)
                            && (ending.charAt(2) == 0 || ending.charAt(2) == 48))
                    {
                        col2 = 9;
                    }
                }

                // end set rows and cols
                System.out.println("Row2 = " + row2 + "\tCol2 = " + col2);

                // Make sure the coordinates are valid start and end
                // coordinates for the given length ship.
                if (((row1 == row2) && ((col2 == col1 + (boatLength - 1)) || (col2 == col1
                        - (boatLength - 1))))
                        || ((col1 == col2) && ((row2 == row1
                                + (boatLength - 1)) || (row2 == row1
                                - (boatLength - 1)))))
                    validCoords = true;

                if (!validCoords)
                    System.out.println("Error:  Invalid coordinates for a "
                            + boatLength + " -length ship.\n");
            } while (!validCoords); // end inner do-while

            // Make sure there is not a boat already in that area.
            // Loop through part of the array and check for 1's and 2's
            // (boat present on coordinate)
            // If there are, a boat is present and these coordinates are
            // therefore invalid.
            if (p.getPlayerNumber() == 1)
            {
                if (row1 == row2)
                {
                    if (col1 + boatLength > 9)
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c > col1 - boatLength; c--)
                            {
                                if (p1[r][c] == 1 || p1[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c < col1 + boatLength; c++)
                            {
                                if (p1[r][c] == 1 || p1[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    if (row1 + boatLength > 9)
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r > row1 - boatLength; r--)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                            {
                                if (p1[r][c] == 1 || p1[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r < row1 + boatLength; r++)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                            {
                                if (p1[r][c] == 1 || p1[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if (p.getPlayerNumber() == 2)
            {
                if (row1 == row2)
                {
                    if (col1 + boatLength > 9)
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c > col1 - boatLength; c--)
                            {
                                if (p2[r][c] == 1 || p2[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c < col1 + boatLength; c++)
                            {
                                if (p2[r][c] == 1 || p2[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else
                {
                    if (row1 + boatLength > 9)
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r > row1 - boatLength; r--)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                            {
                                if (p2[r][c] == 1 || p2[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        for (int r = row1; r < row1 + boatLength; r++)
                        {
                            for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                            {
                                if (p2[r][c] == 1 || p2[r][c] == 2)
                                    boatPresent = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (boatPresent)
                System.out
                        .println("Error:  Invalid coordinates, a boat is present in this location.");

        } while (boatPresent); // end outer do-while

        // Place the boat on the ocean
        if (p.getPlayerNumber() == 1)
        {
            if (row1 == row2)
            {
                if (col1 + boatLength - 1 > 9
                        || (starting.charAt(1) > ending.charAt(1)))
                {
                    for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1, counter = 0; c > col1
                                - boatLength; c--, counter++)
                        {
                            // place boat
                            p1[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1, counter = 0; c < col1
                                + boatLength; c++, counter++)
                        {
                            p1[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
            // Columns the same
            {
                // Going backwards
                if (row1 + boatLength - 1 > 9
                        || (starting.charAt(0) > ending.charAt(0)))
                {
                    for (int r = row1, counter = 0; r > row1 - boatLength; r--, counter++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                        {
                            p1[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else
                // going forwards
                {
                    for (int r = row1, counter = 0; r < row1 + boatLength; r++, counter++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                        {
                            p1[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP1[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (p.getPlayerNumber() == 2)
        {
            if (row1 == row2)
            {
                if (col1 + boatLength - 1 > 9
                        || (starting.charAt(1) > ending.charAt(1)))
                {
                    for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1, counter = 0; c > col1
                                - boatLength; c--, counter++)
                        {
                            p2[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    for (int r = row1; r < row1 + 1; r++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1, counter = 0; c < col1
                                + boatLength; c++, counter++)
                        {
                            p2[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else
            // Columns the same
            {
                if (row1 + boatLength - 1 > 9
                        || (starting.charAt(0) > ending.charAt(0)))
                {
                    // Going backwards
                    for (int r = row1, counter = 0; r > row1 - boatLength; r--, counter++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                        {
                            p2[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else
                // going forwards
                {
                    for (int r = row1, counter = 0; r < row1 + boatLength; r++, counter++)
                    {
                        for (int c = col1; c < col1 + 1; c++)
                        {
                            p2[r][c] = 1;
                            // Record coordinates in the static arrays for
                            // boat location
                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatOneLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatTwoLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatThreeLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFourLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][0] = r;
                                    boatFiveLocationP2[counter][1] = c;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // userChoices[num-1] = 1; update statements
        userChoices[num - 1] = 1;
        menuChoices[num - 1] = 0;

        // Check to see if we are ready to continue out of the loop.
        notReady = true;
        if (userChoices[0] == 1 && userChoices[1] == 1
                && userChoices[2] == 1 && userChoices[3] == 1
                && userChoices[4] == 1)
            notReady = false;
        System.out.println();
    } while (notReady);
}
```

Everything seems to work just fine when I run the program in a driver class, unless during the lines....

```
// Get user input
System.out.print("\nEnter your menu choice:  ");
num = kb.nextInt();
```

.... the user enters a String.  In that case, the compiler throws an InputMismatchException.

I **understand** why I'm getting this error, but how can I prevent the user from inputting a String?  I thought that the two while() statements I have following the user-input line would take care of that, but if given a String it still throws an Exception...

Any ideas on how to fix this?  By the way, this is my first post here, so sorry if I posted way too much code.  Figured I'd be more specific than vague.

EDIT:  Thank you C.B. , ccjmne, and ryvantage, and everyone else who replied.  All of your input led me to my final solution, which I'm showing below.  If there's a better way of doing it, please let me know.

```
//Prompt user for menu choice
                try
                {
                    // Prompt user
                    System.out.print("Enter your menu choice:  ");

                    // Get input from user
                    num = kb.nextInt();
                } catch (InputMismatchException e)
                {
                    System.out
                            .println("Error, invalid input.  Try again.\n");
                    kb.next();
                }

                kb.nextLine();

                // Input Validation- input must be a valid menu choice
                while ((num != 1 && num != 2 && num != 3 && num != 4 && num != 5))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Prompt user
                        System.out.print("Enter your menu choice:  ");

                        // Get input from user
                        num = kb.nextInt();
                    } catch (InputMismatchException e)
                    {
                        System.out
                                .println("Error, invalid input.  Try again.\n");
                    }
                    kb.nextLine();
                }
                // Further Validation- Make sure number has not been picked
                // before yet
                while (userChoices[num - 1] == 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Prompt user
                        System.out.print("Enter your menu choice:  ");

                        // Get input from user
                        num = kb.nextInt();
                    } catch (InputMismatchException e)
                    {
                        System.out
                                .println("Error, invalid input.  Try again.\n");
                    }
                    kb.nextLine();
                }
```

Comment: *Hint*, look at the [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) method.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393156/error-handling-reading-ints-from-scanner-in-while-loop -- not precisely the same question but the answer should give you hints. Incidentally, does anybody know if there is a canonical "Help, my Scanner.nextXXX() calls are choking on invalid input!" question? These have been popping up a lot today.

Comment: @Paweth: In short; you can't *prevent* the user from entering a string, but you can use `Scanner.next()` or `Scanner.nextLine()` to *read* a string, then you can attempt to parse it as an integer (see [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))). in a separate step and notify the user that they screwed up if it fails (by handling the exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `catch` the `InputMismatchException` and loop back around so that you can continue. Basically, your code needs to be:

```
while (userChoices[num - 1] == 1)
{
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter your menu choice:  ");
        num = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error. Invalid input. Try again."); // Or whatever error message you want.
    }
}
```

To further your programming skills, you should read up more about [Exception handling in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

EDIT: Typically, you want to avoid catching Exceptions as a means of controlling program flow. The best practice is to **avoid** exceptions through better logic, but I'm really not well versed with console-based I/O, so I have no idea how you'd manage that. Especially when parsing numbers from `String`s, I usually just use a try/catch hehe #guilty

Comment: If you're going to call `nextLine()` in every case anyways, you might as well *only* use `nextLine()` and save your exception handling for `Integer.parseInt()` calls.

Comment: Ahh, well I'm not entirely sure what `nextLine()` does so I just wrapped all the code in a try block. What does it do? And why is it being called?

Comment: I'm not familiar with try/catch statements.  Does it automatically loop back to the top of the try-block upon completion of the catch-block?

Comment: @Paweth, The code in the `try` block is executed, and if an error is thrown, then the code in the `catch` block is executed (and every line between the error and the catch block is skipped). If the code in the catch block does not `return` or throw another error, it exits like normal flowing code. If your `while` condition is still `true`, then yes it will loop back through the `while` code.

Comment: Basically, if `nextInt()` throws an error, then the program will jump to the `catch` block. Then, it will display a message and continue as normal (still skipping the code between the error and the `catch` block).

Answer (score 1):

**Welcome to StackOverflow and to the world of programming!**

You cannot literally *prevent the user from inputting a [non-numeric] String*. Those users are clueless b*stards who just input anything then can think of :)

There is something you can do, though. You can ask them to try again and again, until they get it right!
Also, to avoid throwing and catching `Exception`, you could use the `Scanner#hasNextInt` method, whose purpose is obvious.

You could try to do the following:

```
while (!kb.hasNextInt()) {
    kb.next();    // this will consume the rubbish input
}

num = kb.nextInt();
```

Cheers!

Comment: Is this bit of code supposed to go before or after the  num = kb.nextInt();  ?  I'm still trying to grasp **what's** actually in the  scanner, where the "cursor" is, and which Scanner methods actually _advance_ the scanner's "cursor."

Comment: Well, this bit of code **includes** `num = kb.nextInt();`... So I would that that you could **replace** it by the code I suggested. Keep your call to `kb.nextLine();` right after! Also, basically, all the methods of a Scanner that **extract and return** something from the underlying stream (typically, the `nextXXX` methods) actually consume some data and "move the cursor". On the other hand, the `hasNextXXX` methods only **test** the "upcoming data" and thus, even though they obviously read it, they don't *consume* it (the "cursor" remains still).